# How to Migrate Git Repositories using migration-tools (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration)

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

How to Migrate Git Repositories using azure-DevOps-migration-tools (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration)

I have added
"GitRepoMapping":{"SourceProjectName":"TargetProjectName "},

However, it is not working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Migration Tools do not migrate Git Repos.

https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools

You have to migrate them yourself then the Migration Tools will fix the Git Commit links from the work items to the repo.